# Different/Incorrect results in calendar field

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, java.util.calendar

I'm trying to add event but it shows a different date that I'm trying to put and what I'm getting.

```
eventButton.setOnClickListener(
        new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar calendarEvent = Calendar.getInstance();
                Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                calendarIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

                Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
                time.clear();
                time.set(2018, 05, 23);

                calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Whatever");
                calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,time.getTimeInMillis());
                calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,time.getTimeInMillis());
                calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY,true);
                calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=YEARLY");
                startActivity(calendarIntent);

            }
        }
);
```

I'm getting this Jun 22, instead of May 23:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKS8V.jpg)

Comment: Please don’t use 05 for 5. It works, but it’s a bad habit since you will get a compile error once you try 08 for 8.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Were you able to fix your issue? Do you need any more help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java `Calendar.set()` method counts months just like arrays in programming, starting from 0 for January. Therefore, your month should be `4` for May, since January is 0, February is 1, March is 2, and so on. That is what I believe is causing your issue.

You may also use the Month enumeration. That is, instead of using your line

```
time.set(2018, 05, 23);
```

Use

```
time.set(2018, Calendar.May, 23);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You're right, this solves the Month problem but the day is again lesser by one, so, is there any other way for the day too or I just have to increment by one the date I've to add?

Comment: @CoDesign I'll get back to you on that shortly, I'm going to look into it and test it myself.

Comment: @CoDesign From the docs, "If allDay is set to 1 eventTimezone must be TIMEZONE_UTC and the time must correspond to a midnight boundary."

That means you should use `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`

Comment: @CoDesign I just tested your code on my emulator with the only change of decrementing your month by one as per my answer, and I get May 23rd, which is what you want. What timezone is your device in? It would be helpful if you could log `calendarEvent.getTimeZone().toString();` and show me it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    long eventTimeInMillis = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.MAY, 23)
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();
```

As Jamie Corkhill said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49843820/different-incorrect-results-in-calendar-field#comment86707030_49845571), you need the time at the start of day (00:00) in UTC. The above code not only gives you the time at 00:00 in UTC, it is also pretty clear about that this is what it gives you.

I am using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. I find it much nicer to work with than the long outdated `Calendar` class.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.